# Java: return static nested class

Tags: java, static, getter, nested-class

I have a static nested class, which I would like to return via a static accessor (getter).

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static class Columns<CC>
    {
        ...

        public static int length = 5;
    }

    public static Columns<?> getColumnEnumerator()
    {
        int x = Columns.length; //no problems

        return Columns; //compiler error
        //cannot find symbol: variable Columns location: blah.blah.SomeClass
    }
}
```

I know why this doesn't work, because Columns is a class, and not a variable, however, for other reasons, I need to keep columns as a static class. I am not even sure if this doable, but just wanna ask if there was?

Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate on what are we trying to achieve here. I am not too sure of what the actual question is :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your static nested class is public, as in your example, I'm wondering why you want to create an accessor while you can directly access the nested class.

Comment: @gizmo, I'm sorry that I left that out of the question, but I was going to create a superclass for `SomeClass`, which returns `Columns`, & `Columns` would be implemented differently in each subclass.

Comment: @bguiz: I think that we're all missing the exact pattern you'r trying to achieve then. Could you be more specific in your question? Giving use cases would be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to instantiate the Class, like:

```
 return new Columns();
```

If columns was not static and you would like to instantiate it from somewhere else it would require an instance of the outer class

```
return new SomeClass().new Columns();
```

With your solution you can do:

```
return new SomeClass.Columns();
```

Comment: @Kristian, `Columns` is an entirely static class (all its members are static), so instantiation isn't really an option here.

Comment: @bguiz, I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve here, static classes and static methods are two different things...?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to return the *class* **Column** or an instance of **Column** ?

For the former, you can use

```
return SomeClass.Columns.class; // SomeClass.Columns can also be accessed directly,
                                // since it is public.
```

For the latter, you can use

```
return new SomeClass.Columns();
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you actually explain how your `Columns` class is to be used. Are you trying to get an instance of it or are you trying to get what class it is?

You can return a `Class` instance to allow your calling method to use `newInstance()` on it:

```
public static Class<Columns> getColumnEnumerator()
{
    int x = Columns.length;

    return Columns.class;
}
```

Or you'll have to modify `Columns` into something like:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static class Columns<CC>
    {
       public final int LENGTH = 5;  // changed to a final, or create an accessor

       ...

       private Columns() { ... }  // private constructor
    }

    public static Columns<?> getColumnEnumerator()
    {
        Columns columns = new Columns();  // only SomeClass can instantiate this
        int x = columns.LENGTH;

        return columns;
    }
}
```

But from one of your comments about "create a superclass for `SomeClass`, which returns `Columns`", this seems to be a design issue. You can't override static methods so inheritance might makes things worse.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static Columns<?> getColumnEnumerator()
```

This means that you need to return an instance of Columns.

How about

```
 return new Columns();
```

or, if you want the same instance all the time

```
 return Columns.privateSingletonInstance;  // from a static field
```